# How to fix the popup position to below the button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to position a popup under  button.

I could change the position to left and right but the popup is coming on top of the screen.

How can I set popup position height?

Here is my code:

**js**

```
      $(function () {
          $("#myDialog").dialog({
               autoOpen: false,

               show: 'fade',
               hide: 'fade',
               modal: false,
               width: 300,
               draggable: false,
               minHeight: 200,
               //buttons: {
               //    "Close": function () {
               //        $(this).dialog("close");
               //    }
               //}
          });

          $("#myLink").click(function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
               return false;
          });

          function positionDialog() {
               linkOffset = $("#myLink").position();
               linkWidth = $("#myLink").width();
               linkHeight = $("#myLink").height();
               scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
               $("#myDialog").dialog("option", "position", [(linkOffset.left - 550/ 2) + linkWidth / 2, (linkOffset.top - 220 / 2 ) + linkHeight - scrolltop]);
           }

           positionDialog();

           $(window).resize(function () {
               positionDialog();
           });

           $(window).scroll(function () {
               positionDialog();
           });
      });
```

**html**

```
<div style="text-align:center; float:left"><a href="#" id="myLink">Login here</a></div>
         <div id="myDialog" title=" Login">
         @Html.Partial("_LoginPopupPartial")                 
</div>
```

Can someone please help me. The popup should come where ever I place my button. and also it should come below the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the popup as a child of the button. Then it's automaticly on the right position.

Comment: could u pls give me some code as i am new to pragraming... any help is appreciated

Comment: according to the API docs it could look like this:

`        $( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: button } });`


[link]http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position[/link]